# 「改善待ち」の質問が編集された場合の対応について

Tags: 討議, 編集

「改善待ち」の質問には新たな回答をすることができませんが、そうなる前に投稿していた回答は編集が可能です。

「改善待ち」の質問が投稿者によって編集された場合、そうなる前に回答していた人はどのように対応するべきでしょうか？

1. 再オープンされるまでなにもしない
   コミュニティの判断で「改善待ち」になっているのだから、同じように、コミュニティの判断で回答ができるようになるまで待つべき？
2. 前に投稿していた回答を編集して、回答を追加する
   そもそも、回答した人は「改善するべき」だと思っていないのだから、回答を続行すればいい？（これもコミュニティの一部？）
3. その他
   このような状況はレアケースなので、当事者の判断で対応すればいい？

具体的には、以下の質問のケースです。
[swift(Xcode7)でスマホアプリを開発していますが](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/21374/swiftxcode7%E3%81%A7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9E%E3%83%9B%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C)

とりあえず、今回は方針がわからなかったので、最低限の情報をコメントする形にしてあります。

Comment: 参考：過去の類似の議論「[回答後の質問の大幅な変更にはどのようにアクションすべきか](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1558/10492)」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

新規回答は制限されますが既存の回答の編集はロックされてないので回答の編集をすべきでないという趣旨ではないでしょう。したがって編集を躊躇う必要は無いと思います。